# How to display stimestamps with microseconds in excel corrctly?

Tags: excel, vba

I got timestamps of the format "06.02.2015 02:34:35.868"
Some of them are displayed like "06.02.2015 02:34" and some corrtly. I tried around a lot with the cell format but did not have any success.

Any advices?
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I try into a cell the custom format: `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss,000` and the result is some that you want.
The only limt I find is 3 digits after ","